# Keep value of date to a default one if no date is selected

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I want to keep the value of a Date to a default value that I specified. If no date is selected when user click submit button.

what I need the functionality to be. If user select a date and submit the form, after submission the form selected date value must be the value on the date field which works perfectly so. I have the problem ie. when date is not selected and user submit form the date field have the today's date by default **Select Date**

My code is as follows

HTML

```
<body  onload="CovertDateToString()">

    <form action="searchDate" method="post" id="searchDate" class="searchDate"  modelAttribute="searchDate">
        <!-- Select type selectDateRange-->
            <div class="form-group ">
                        <div class="col-md-3 selectContainer">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="selectDateRange" id="selectDateRange" value="${newDate}">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i  class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span> 
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          <!-- Select type search button with input-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-3 inputGroupContainer">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span   class="input-group-btn">
                     <button class="btn btn-success"  type="submit">
                        <div class="up" style="margin-top: -8%; color: white;">Search</div></button>
                     </span>
                   </div>
                 <!-- /input-group -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Js code

```
function CovertDateToString() { 

    var date = <%=request.getParameter("selectDateRange")%>;    
    var myDate = new Date();
    var selectDate = myDate.toDateString();
    var selectDate = "Select Date"; 
    document.getElementsByName('selectDateRange')[0].value = selectDate;
    selectDate = date;
    document.getElementsById('selectDateRange')[0].value = date;
    console.log("Set Date to Select Date ",selectDate);
    console.log("Set Date to Selected Date ",date);
}
```

daterangepicker

```
$(function() {      
    $('input[name="selectDateRange"]').daterangepicker({              
        locale: {
             format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: provide a clear running code possible the on fiddle.

Comment: Okay I will create a fiddle for this.

Comment: Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/JayStar/0mrm64rb/8/. For this line `<%=request.getParameter("selectDateRange")%>;` I use jsp tags so on fiddle it wont work.

Comment: `var date = "${newDate}";` this should work.

Comment: Thats what I fixed, thanks @King.

Answer (score 1):

```
        function CovertDateToString() { 

            var date = "${newDate}";    
            var myDate = new Date();
            var selectDate = myDate.toDateString();
            document.getElementsByName('selectDateRange')[0].value = selectDate;
            selectDate = date;
            document.getElementById('selectDateRange').value = date;
            console.log("Set Date to Select Date ",selectedDate);
            console.log("Set Date to Selected Date ",date);

        }    

       $(function() {      
        $('input[name="selectDateRange"]').daterangepicker({              
          locale: {
             format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
            }
          });
       });
```

After more hours on this issue I final got it to work. Removing the request.getParamter was the mean reason date got removed after

Answer (score -1):

Please check the following code i have used static values at the place of dynamic values so manage it and code is working fine at snnipet.

```js
  

 function CovertDateToString() { 
    var date = "${newDate}";
 
    var arr = date.split(" ");
    if(arr != "null"){
     $("#selectDateRange").data('daterangepicker').setStartDate(arr[0]);
     $("#selectDateRange").data('daterangepicker').setEndDate(arr[2]);
    }
}
    $(function() {      
        $('input[name="selectDateRange"]').daterangepicker({              
            locale: {
                 format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>

    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <body  onload="CovertDateToString()">

        <form action="searchDate" method="post" id="searchDate" class="searchDate"  modelAttribute="searchDate">
            <!-- Select type selectDateRange-->
                <div class="form-group ">
                            <div class="col-md-3 selectContainer">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="selectDateRange" id="selectDateRange" >
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i  class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span> 
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              <!-- Select type search button with input-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-3 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span   class="input-group-btn">
                         <button class="btn btn-success"  type="submit">
                            <div class="up" style="margin-top: -8%; color: white;">Search</div></button>
                         </span>
                       </div>
                     <!-- /input-group -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
```

Comment: This only works if I have not selected a date and submit the form. If I select a date the **Select Date** must be replace by selected date after submitting the form.

Comment: This pass a string to input not Select Date

Comment: @shivam this creates an invalid date, and the calenders dates appear to be NAN all of them.

Comment: @King this code is fetching from server side and i explain here how the code is working it is a dummy code. If you are working with server side then code is working fine. Explain why you down vote me. Kindly Up vote me

Comment: @King <%=request.getParameter("selectDateRange")%> this is a jsp code not a HTML code so it is working fine with jsp not on HTML Page so try on JSP Page

Comment: @Shivam the user Select Date comes from Server side, not the date. On the date, the user selects the date then send it to server side. The js script is used to hold what the user has selected.

Comment: `<%=request.getParameter("selectDateRange")%>` does not hold anything on page load.

Comment: yes but at that time it is null and it take current date at on page load case

Comment: this is the guy `${newDate}` that hold the value on page hold. According to what I see in the code.

Comment: What happens if the user doesn't not select date? Cause @JayStar said by default the date is set to **Select Date** meaning it cant be null. There a 
 is a Select Date if the user does not select a specific date.

Comment: @King My code is working fine I run this code at my end it is working fine if possible then check at on your end here i am using apche server with jsp and struts2 framework.

Comment: @shivam, I will run a test buddy.

Comment: @shivam it does not set the "**Select Date**" as default. It set today's date as default.

Comment: @shivam I did run a test with your latest code, but the default is set to today's date. I want to default to be set to Select Date. Cause here I'm using moment.js as my lib to help with date range picker, so moment wont allow you to set a placeholder, it will set it but and it fade away and set today's date of which I don't want.